# What correlation structure is necessary to ensure a random walk is almost surely bounded?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk, brownian-motion

Say I have a stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that their cumulative sum $\{S_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a random walk process:

$$
S_t = \sum_{i = 1}^t X_i
$$

If each $X_t$ is i.i.d and takes values in $\{-1, 1\}$ with equal probability, then $\{S_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a simple random walk, and hence unbounded.  Specifically, any trajectory will hit $\pm \sqrt{t}$ infinitely many times almost surely:

> [image]
>
> Each blue line is a sample trajectory of $\{S_t\}$ for $t \in [0, 1000]$.  100 sample trajectories are shown, and  $\pm \sqrt{t}$  is overlaid in red.

But say one wishes to have a random walk which is almost surely bounded above and below.  How should $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ be changed? Clearly it can’t be i.i.d. anymore, but what correlation structure is necessary?

To be a touch more precise:

If $\{S_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a cumulative sum of the stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$

$$
S_t = \sum_{i = 1}^t X_i
$$

what conditions on $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ are necessary to ensure that

$$
\exists M \in \mathbb{R} \,\,\,\,\,\, \forall t \in \mathbb{N} \,\,\,\,\,\, |S_t| \leq M \,\,\,\,\,\, \text{a.s.}
$$

and so that $\{S_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ still "looks" like a random walk for all $t \in \mathbb{N}$.  I'm not sure how to be rigorous about this condition, but I'll try by saying that our source of noise $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ should not diminish over time:

$$
\forall t \in \mathbb{N} \,\,\,\,\, \exists t' > t \,\,\,\,\, E[|X_{t'}|] \geq E[|X_{t}|]
$$

---

I assumed this would be an elementary exercise, but after trying on my own, I'm finding it difficult.  By trying out a few different dependence structures, I either end up with an $\{S_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ whose trajectories converge to a flat line, or diverge to infinity eventually.

I also haven't found much help searching keywords like "random walk of finite variation" or "bounded correlated random walk," but I'm not an expert, so I might just be overlooking search results that are actually what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi: Somehow you have to bound the variance of the process but I have no idea how since the variance of the sum  of the $X_{i}$ grows linearly with $t$. I'm not a mathematician but I guess you'd have to have the variance depend on $t$ so that it decreases an $t$ increases.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @mlofton.  Do you imagine having the variance of $X_t$ decrease with $t$?

Comment: Hi: No but I can't think of any other way to bound a random walk ? Maybe have some kind of barrrier process where, when the RW process hits the absolute value of a number, it automatically goes the other way with probability 1.0. This question is more for a probabilist-mathematician type. I was just thinking of what might be possible.

Comment: @mlofton The variance need not grow when there are enough *negative* covariance terms.  Intuitively, there must exist some kind of feedback mechanism that continually brings the sum back toward zero.  That, plus a stationarity assumption, give strong, constructive guidance concerning the necessary covariance structure.

Comment: @whuber: I get some of what you said but the random walk doesn't have any covariance structure so  could you give an example because I don't quite follow that part and I know that you know what you're talking about so its me. not you. thanks.

Comment: @mlofton Suppose, for instance, that $(X_t)$ is an AR(1) process with negative lag-one correlation: that's an example of what I believe the OP might mean by "correlation structure." Now, it's not possible for a process taking values in $\{-1,1\}$ to be AR(1), but one can nevertheless construct such a process having negative correlation. As an extreme example, let $X_0$ be a Rademacher variable and for all $t\ge 0$ let $X_{t+1}=-X_t$ (negative feedback). For this process, $S_t$ alternates between $-1$ and $0$ or it alternates between $1$ and $0,$ depending on $X_0,$ and obviously is bounded.

Comment: gotcha. I see what you mean. I thought the OP was trying to restrict himself to random walk processes but maybe not. thanks.